# returning static member for virtual function, missing vtable for abstract class

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, vtable, undefined-function

Newcomer in cpp here, be advised, possibly dumbness ahead.

I was trying to return a static property when implementing a virtual function. This issue a linker error saying that the function wasn't implemented. I'm lost with this issue.

I was able to reproduce the error with the following stripped down code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Abstract1 {
public:
    virtual char* getFoo();
};

class Base: public Abstract1 {
public:
    char* getFoo() {
        return Base::mapper[1];
    }
    static std::map<int,char*> mapper;
};

std::map<int, char*> Base::mapper;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Base::mapper[0] = "Hello!\n";
    Base::mapper[1] = "Goodbye!\n";
    Base* hello = new Base();
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << hello->getFoo() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Yielding the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for Abstract1", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Base in main.o
  "vtable for Abstract1", referenced from:
      Abstract1::Abstract1() in main.o
```

Comment: You will also need to add a virtual destructor if you intend to delete from an `Abstract1` pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Abstract1::getFoo` is simply virtual, not abstract.

You can either make it abstract : `virtual char * getFoo() = 0;` or provide a default implementation.

Comment: That's it! I thought those are the same thing... I guess I was wrong. Need to learn more! Thanks!

Comment: np, btw the actual term is [*pure virtual*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class)